# Connect to specific MarkLogic database via node slushjs

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp, marklogic

I'm using the slushjs generator for MarkLogic projects with node.

Rather than connecting to a new database that the slush generates, I'd like to connect to the existing, default Documents database.

```
Server Name: App-Services

Database: Documents

Port: 8000
```

Does anyone know which files I need to edit do such a connection? I've tried editing multiple files such as the deploy/build.properties, deploy/default.properties, deploy/local.properties, gulp file, etc.

But I've had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two config files relevant here:

1. `{env}`.json
2. `deploy\{env}.properties`

where `{env}` can be `local`, `dev`, or `prod`.

The first configures the NodeJS middle-tier that proxies calls from front-end to MarkLogic, next to serving statics, and handling authentication sessions. You'll be looking for the `ml-http-port` setting inside there.

The second is used by the Roxy-deployer that comes with slush-marklogic-node. It is mainly used to create app-specific databases, and servers (good for code and content isolation), setup security (if needed), and deploy things like REST-api configuration, extensions, and transforms. In there you'd be looking for the `app-port` property, but setting that to `8000` will do you no good. Roxy will attempt to create an app-specific server on that port, but that is occupied by MarkLogic itself.

You probably want to either:

- ignore app-specific MarkLogic configuration, and only edit `{env}.json`, and ignore `deploy/` altogether
- or point your app-specific configuration towards the already existing `Documents` database, basically by changing the `content-db` property to `Documents`. Roxy will adjust indexes and settings of that database though, unless you take further action.

HTH!